# Two questions about hard understanding Java code

Tags: java, number-formatting, java-6, blockingqueue

I am reading Java source code, encounter two little questions. I don't know why Sun write code like this, here are questions (JDK version:1.6):

**Question 1:**

```
java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue#offer(E e):


public boolean offer(E e) {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        boolean ok = q.offer(e);
        assert ok;
        notEmpty.signal();
        return true;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Why to define a local final `ReentrantLock` variable in method block, why not directly to use a global variable `lock`?

**Question 2:**

This method `java.text.NumberFormat#getInstance(Locale desiredLocale, int choice):` creates a `DecimalFormat` object, but a return type is `NumberFormat`. Why not to make return type as `DecimalFormat`?

Comment: You might want to separate this into 2 totally separate questions, since they are unrelated

Comment: @DWright: yes, I will do this in the future, thanks for your recommendation

Comment: The API is what it is. Asking why is pretty pointless unless you can get hold of the guy who wrote it. #1 seems entirely pointless to me unless it relates to the memory model rules. Re #2, note that all the `getInstance()` methods return `NumberFormat,` not just that one.

Answer (score 3):

To the first question:

1. That is not a global variable, that is a member variable. I do suggest that you look into scoping rules to get a better idea of the vocabulary.
2. There are a couple of possibilities for why a programmer might make this decision. Most immediately I am reminded of the Android SDK where there is a mild performance increase when you use a locally scoped variable. It also might be that the programmer felt that using `final` would be a better choice in this instance (more on *why* that might happen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29).).

To the second question:

It returns a `DecimalFormat` most of the time, but it is possible (and you can see [the source here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/NumberFormat.java#NumberFormat.getInstance%28java.util.Locale,int%29)) for the `getInstance` method to return a different descendant of `NumberFormat`.

Comment: to your first point: I am wrong, it is a member variable, thanks. to your second point: member variable 'lock' is already defined as final: private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true); I think the author define a locally scoped variable in method block is just making an unnecessary move.

Answer (score 1):

1. Locally scoped variable not intended to modify.
2. `NumberFormat` is an abstract class, so it's treated like interface.